# Get n LSB from Integer C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift, significant-digits

So I'm getting an unsigned int passed into my function. Now I must obtain the n LSB bits of that integer and use it to access a location in an array of size `2^n`.

So for example, if my array is of size 1024, n = 10.

I am currently doing this:

```
unsigned int location = my_unsigned_int << n;
```

However this doesn't work as `location` ends up being way too large and out of bounds.

Comment: Try to do it on paper first, to see that you get it correctly. And to give you a hint, you need to *mask out* the top-level bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just mask the bits you want:

```
unsigned int location = my_unsigned_int & ((1<<n) - 1);
```

This assumes that your `int` is at least `n+1` bits in size.

Comment: I think you mean only one `&` because the `&&` isn't bitwise

Comment: It's giving me an error "suggest parentheses around '-' inside <<"